# Nteflix streams really choppy

Tags: wine

I installed netflix on edubuntu 12.04lts. it will stream movies but is real choppy. I know its not my comp  unable to handle because i use to have windows on here and it ran fine. Is there any fixes to get the choppiness to stop

Comment: Now did you install Netflix exactly? I thought Netflix did not support Ubuntu from reading other questions and that the workarounds were really inferior. Please *edit* your question to include more details. Also consider including more about your system specifications and GPU card/driver in use.

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu, you are running netflix through `wine`, a sort of Windows emulation software, because Netflix won't support Linux. This is not so efficient as running the Netflix software natively. I've found it can work, but it seems to be sensitive to **everything** else running on your system as well as the quality of your wifi signal.

Try it with a good wifi signal with nothing else running.